# Need help understanding the using an ID and Class together in my CSS

Tags: html, css, drupal

I am working in Drupal and I would like my CSS to style specific sections of the assigned page "node". I would also like to give those assignments to multiple nodes. This is what my CSS looks like but it only works when I assign the nodes separately instead of together. Therefore I am assuming that must be writing my CSS incorrectly.

Basically I want the class="pagetitleheader" to not display within specific nodes:

```
#node-66310 .pagetitleheader,
#node-66779 .pagetitleheader,
#node-66812 .pagetitleheader,
#node-66317 .pagetitleheader,
#node-66265 .pagetitleheader {
     display:none;
}
```

Comment: I don't know drupal, but is there maybe a possibility to add another class to this nodes? I think if not, there is no other solution than yours, which is not really smooth.

Comment: From what I can see you have done it correctly. Do you happen to have a link to share?

Answer (score 0):

You have "context" module which can give your body html element additional class when context conditions are met. So you can use that body class to aim only those specific pages. And conditions can be a simple list of pages as you have here, but also i.e. page in specific content type or page belongs to some menu or something else. After that you can simply write CSS like:

```
body.myClass .pagetitleheader{
   display:none;
}
```

And context will add that "myClass" class to  where it's needed.